# How to remove material input style from Angular material chip?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using material chips to give multi-select functionality in one of my forms.

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
   <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits;let indx=index;" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit,indx)">
         {{fruit.name}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input placeholder="Enter business categories" #fruitInput [formControl]="fruitCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur">
   </mat-chip-list>
   <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
         {{fruit.name}}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

The problem I'm facing is the material stying in the input field.

[image]

This material input field disturbs the form look and feel. How do I use a custom input field instead of material input?

Answer (score 1):

The mat-form-field has an attribute called appearance

Change it to:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" appearance="fill">
```

And use css to remove the underline

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Although this resolves the material input animation but the underline in the input still remains: https://prnt.sc/1qglxea. Any leads on how to fix it?

Comment: already edit the answer to remove the underline.